# Access database in BeforeFeature

Tags: symfony, behat

How do I access my database via doctrine in a BeforeFeature?  I am unable to get my entity manager because my kernel is null...this is what I am trying:

```
/**
 * @BeforeFeature
 */
public static function cleanDatabase(FeatureEvent $event)
{
    $context = new FeatureContext(array());
    $context->thereAreNoUsersInTheDatabase();
}
```

It tells me that I cannot get container from a non-object (the kernel).  Why isn't KernelAwareInterface assigning the kernel when I manually create that FeatureContext?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to try to access the container? I am doing a similar thing and mine works fine, using KernelAwareInterface, and getting `$this->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();`

Answer (score 0):

KernelAwareInterface just provides a method "setKernel" method, you still have to call manually if you instantiate a new FeatureContext object

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't know how to pass it a valid kernel.  $this->kernel is valid, but not accessible in a static method.  I know I need to run $context->setKernel($kernel)....but where do I get the kernel in a static method?

Comment: Why do you need this method to be static ? And where is placed this cleanCatabase method ?

Comment: BeforeFeature hooks are required to be static.  With the exception of putting a line in my .feature file, how else can I make sure that the db is cleaned before the feature but not before each scenario.  I would use a "Background" scenario if I didn't need the data to persist through the entire feature.  My cleanDatabase method is located in my FeatureContext.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FriendlyContext that provide you a "@reset-schema" annotation. See https://github.com/KnpLabs/FriendlyContexts/blob/master/doc/context-entity.md#reset-schema .

Do not hesitate to read the full documentation and the code that doesn't uses the SymfonyExtension.